# Por que me muestra errores al importar tkinter en VSC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Es muy extraño porque se ejecuta bien mi código pero sigue saliendome esta especie de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando una sintaxis desaconsejada:

```
from modulo import *
```

ya que ese `*` representa *todos los símbolos definidos en ese módulo*, lo cual se desaconseja por varias razones:

1. Legibilidad. Si usas diferentes módulos y en todos ellos haces un `from modulo import *`, cuando luego en el código encuentras una llamada a una función ¿cómo sabes de qué módulo vino? Esto es importante para otra persona que lea tu programa sin conocer a fondo todos los módulos usados y quiera buscar información sobre una función en particular. Incluso tu *yo futuro* cuenta como *otra persona*.
2. Evitar colisiones. ¿Qué pasa si el módulo `foo` define un símbolo llamado `contar`, y el módulo `bar` también? Cuando hagas `from foo import *` y después `from bar import *`, ¿cuál de los dos se usará al llamar a `contar()`? La respuesta, depende del orden en que los importes, lo cual puede causar multitud de problemas.

El método recomendado es simplemente:

```
import modulo
```

y después, cada vez que uses un símbolo definido en ese módulo, usas `modulo.simbolo`. Esto elimina ambos problemas antes mencionados.

Si el nombre del módulo es muy largo y te da pereza teclearlo, siempre puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import modulo as m
```

Después puedes usar `m.simbolo` en lugar de `modulo.simbolo`. Esto evita el segundo problema aunque incurre un poco en el primero. Se ve muy frecuentemente con `pandas`, que se importa como `pd` y `numpy` que se importa como `np`.

Si quieres evitar el prefijo de módulo, y sólo vas a usar unos pocos símbolos de ese módulo, puedes poner:

```
from modulo import simbolo1, simbolo2
```

y de ese modo tu programa puede usar `simbolo1` y `simbolo2` en vez de `modulo.simbolo1` y `modulo.simbolo2`. Esto incurre un poco en el problema 1 (aunque siempre se puede buscar el lugar del `import` para ver de qué módulo vino), y si no tienes cuidado también en el problema 2, pero menos al obligarte a ser más explicita disminuyes la probabilidad de colisiones de nombres.

VSCode usa *linting* mientras escribes, que es un proceso que examina tu código a la búsqueda de posibles errores y *malas practicas*. Según qué *linter* use, el importar cosas que después no utilizas se considera una mala práctica (*warning*).

Si tu programa tiene un `from modulo import simbolo1`, y luego no usa `simbolo1`, el *linter* se quejará.  Naturalmente el problema es mucho más grave si usas un `from modulo import *`, ya que entonces tiene muchos más símbolos de qué quejarse.